# Why do the wings in these pictures go from swept back to parallel with the airflow?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, airliner

To better understand my question, look at this A320 below
[image]

As you can see, the wing becomes parallel with the airflow at the wing root. Same thing on this 737
[image]

But this is not found on bigger planes like the 747 or A380. What is the propose of this?
[image]

Comment: You mean **perpendicular** to the airflow? Also, does [**this**](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/29976/why-is-the-trailing-edge-sweep-angle-smaller-at-the-wing-root) answer your question?

Comment: It does, thanks!