# How does a trailing edge flap move on an Airbus A320?

Tags: wing, airbus-a320, flaps

> Airbus flaps move in flight direction [[link]](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/30057/62316)

I don't exactly understand how that works, do they move just 180 degrees (opposite direction) of the flight path or is it something else? And doesn't every airliner have flaps moving this way (opposite direction of flight path)

Answer (score 1):

If you compare the picture of the B737 in the answer you linked with the one of an A320, you'll see that both set of flaps move in the same way while deploying (see arrow):

[image]
*(B737 belly, [source](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29976/64684))*

[image]
*(A320 belly, [source](https://www.designboom.com/art/photographs-capturing-the-underbelly-of-aircrafts/))*

Most probably there's a mistake in that answer.